# Pasar variable de un sampler a otro Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un BeanShell processor el cual ejecuto un jar y obtengo unos valores para añadirlos al header de una petición http. Tiene la siguiente pinta:

```
import es.JwtGenerator;

JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator();

String[] headerValues = new String[3];
headerValues = jwtGenerator.generateNewJWT();

vars.put("authentication", headerValues[0]);
vars.put("date", headerValues[1]);
vars.put("content-type", headerValues[2]);
```

El jar se ejecuta bien y se hago un print los saco por la pantalla de la consola.

Ahora trato de que los valores que almacené en el BeanShell processor los pueda recoger en la HTTP Request y montar una URI. El problema es que no se como pasar de un sampler del mismo Thread a otro valores. Tal y como lo tengo puesto ahora me lo pilla de manera literal. Eso es lo que creo pero doy por seguro que no recoge el valor de la variable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Dentro de un mismo Thread de JMeter se puede acceder a toda variable que se haya guardado usando el espacio vars. Entonces dentro del BanSheelSampler he almacenado el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
vars.put("date", headerValues[1]);
```

Y en un HttpHeaderManager añadí el valor de la siguiente manera:

```
${date}
```